# Arrow Character Issue

Tags: html, vb.net, unicode, ascii

I receive excel files in a specified folder for inventory upload. When these upload my system is throwing an error of invalid InventoryId. The last row of data comes with an arrow character that when copied and pasted shows a blank space.

Does anyone know what this right arrow character is? 
**It is not HTML, ASCII, or Unicode.**

I need to create a validation on that character not to bring the row if this is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue!

What I did was find what the Character was using the following code:

```
AscW(CurrentRecord(0).ToString) = Variable
```

Once I found what the character was I used the same line in an if statement to solve the issue. See Below.

```
If Not AscW(CurrentRecord(0).ToString) = "26" Then
     If Not CurrentRecord(0).ToString = "InventoryId" Then

        NewRow("InventoryId") = CurrentRecord(0)
        NewRow("Quantity") = CurrentRecord(1)
        NewRow("CostCentre") = CurrentRecord(2)
        NewRow("UsageDate") = CurrentRecord(3)

        InventoryLoad.Tables(0).Rows.Add(NewRow)

        NewRow = InventoryLoad.Tables("Load").NewRow
      End If

ElseIf AscW(CurrentRecord(0).ToString) = "26" Then

Else
CommonFunctions.ErrorEmail("ProductId " & CurrentRecord(0).ToString & " was not recognized", "LoadInventory - ProductId")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following to remove the Unicode characters.

```
 Dim Str As String = "My Stȟring of ChaǕracters"
 Str = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(Str, "[^\u0000-\u007F]", "")
```

or if you wanted to identify Strings then do something

```
 Dim Str As String = "My String of Characters"
 Dim UniCodeCollection As System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(Str, "[^\u0000-\u007F]")

 If UniCodeCollection.Count > 0 Then
     'Add code to do somthing here
 End If
```

Comment: That would not be useful if the inventory had items like crème brûlée.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Sure the above code is to remove all Unicode characters. if you need to keep the accent characters then you just need to amend the Regex to what ever is needed.  An example to include most of the accent characters would be like `[^\u0000-\u007F,^\u00E0-\u017E]`. This would keep your crème brûlée...

Answer (score 0):

As the right-arrow character has been passed via a string, it *must* be a Unicode character.

If the program into which you paste the suspect character is not capable of displaying it, e.g. it is using a font without a visible representation of it, then it may well appear as a blank.

You need to track down what the code is for the character.

The character will *probably* be able to be shown in Visual Studio, so copy-and-paste the offending string in place of "Crème brûlée →" in the following code and examine the output for anything which stands out:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim s = "Crème brûlée →"
        For i = 0 To s.Length - 1
            Console.WriteLine(AscW(s(i)))
        Next
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Outputs:

```
67
114
232
109
101
32
98
114
251
108
233
101
32
8594
```

In the above, 8594 (which is &H2192) stands out as being very different. You now just need to check if `s.IndexOf(ChrW(8594)) >= 0`, which indicates that the character is in the string.